# Why does my drupal 7 redirect me to the home page from any link?

Tags: uri, redirection

I have just enabled clean URLs via admin panel, but now...

it doesn't matter what I click, all my urls redirect me to my home page.

you can try for yourselves by clicking any of the links: http://www.gelpalhano.org/drupal/

and none of the admin links work either, so I can't even disable clean URLs to make sure that is the problem. logout also does not work.

any light you can shed on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: even copying and pasting a page url has no effect: try http://gelpalhano.org/drupal/node/2

Comment: This might help you. [http://drupal.org/node/3854](http://drupal.org/node/3854) and [http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls)

Comment: Please do note however that the first comment on the first link says the document is out of date. The server-implementation details on the second link are strictly for Apache 2.

Comment: Try to replace the `.htaccess` that will correct your clean URLs problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you redirected the default user login page to somwhere else.

When I go to http://www.gelpalhano.org/?q=user, I get a HTTP 302 moved temp, followed by a 301 moved perm, followed by a 200 OK to http://www.gelpalhano.org/site/ (what appears to be your homepage).

Generally clean-urls would fail because your .htaccess if not configured properly, or because your web server is not configured properly. I saw your web host's headers say that the server is of type Microsoft, so I would not be able to suggest a fix for your particular setup (I only use the LAMP stack).

I can suggest however that to regain back access to your site, you substitute `www.gelpalhano.org/?q=user` for `www.gelpalhano.org/?q=[the relative path to your user login page]`, and then once you've logged in, you can go to `www.gelpalhano.org/?q=[the path where you turn on/off clean urls]` and turn them off while you trouble shoot the issue. IMHO, this is a server setup issue, and I think you have more chances of having your issue resolved by researching and posting the same question at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). Good luck and hope that my answer helps.

Comment: actually the problem does not seem with drupal itself, but is related to .htaccess, windows hosting and clean urls: I have a wordpress website which is in a sibling directory of the /drupal directory. This _public_html/site configured with .htaccess to redirect traffic on subpages to /site. so that's that. I'm moving servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once, I copied a site from my testing environment (with clean urls enabled) to a testing environment (without clean urls).  Clean urls shows as being ON in drupal settings even though the server wasn't supporting it at the time.

So I navigated to www.example.com/q?=admin/settings/clean-urls and turned it off. All my links (though unclean) began to work.

Comment: I can't even access that url. www.gelpalhano.org/q?=admin/settings/clean-urls redirects me to http://gelpalhano.org/drupal/node