# User having issue with site being redirected to home page from every link

Tags: 7, redirection

We have a drupal 7 site hosted on a linux machine. One of our users claims they get redirected to the home page from every link they click on the site. I'm not personally having this experience with the site nor is anyone else I work with. The user hasn't given us any more information, but I'm wondering if you guys have any idea what might be going on here?

I found this thread but it seems to be mostly a Windows-based issue: [Why does my drupal 7 redirect me to the home page from any link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17851/why-does-my-drupal-7-redirect-me-to-the-home-page-from-any-link). Plus I have clean URLs on and like I said it works fine for everyone else.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using Apache? Is there an htaccess file in the drupal root?

Comment: @AyeshK yes on both counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possibly an issue with a cookie. Have that user try to use another browser to check if the same problem occurs with that browser.

Or just delete the session cookie in the browser being used, then check if the issue is resolved.

Comment: that seems a reasonable suggestion, I'll follow up with the user.

Comment: no news; user must have figured it out and not told us. We gave him your ideas though, so I'll give you credit for it.